# What's Wrong With My Bash Script? (line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `elif')

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax

I've following a Lynda.com course online.

I'm trying to learn all I can but I still struggle with Command Substitution, Arrays and a If loops sometimes.

```
#!/bin/bash
MLOG="/var/log/mail.log"
SLOG="/var/log/syslog"

echo "Which log(s) do you want to see? " 

echo "[1]   Head Of Mail.log?"
echo "[2]   Head Of Syslog?"
echo "[3]   Tail Of Mail.log?"
echo "[4]   Tail Of Syslog?"
echo "[5]   Dump Mail.log to File?"
echo "[6]   Dump Syslog to File?"


read -p "Select an option [1-6]: " OPTION

if
test "$OPTION" -eq "1"
then

head $MLOG

elif
test "$OPTION" -eq "2"
then
head $SLOG

elif
test "$OPTION" -eq "3"
tail $MLOG

elif
test "$OPTION" -eq "4"
tail $SLOG

elif
test "$OPTION" -eq "5"
cat  "$MLOG" > ./MessageLogDump.txt
echo "Message.Log Successfully Dumped in PWD"

elif
test "$OPTION" -eq "6"
cat  "$SLOG" > ./SysLog.txt
echo "Syslog Successfully Dumped in PWD"

else $? -ne "0"
echo "Something went wrong somewhere"

else z $OPTION
echo "You selected an incorrect option"
fi
```

There Error I receive on any output: Even with just STDIN of "1"

```
./GenSysLog.sh: line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./GenSysLog.sh: line 43: `      elif'
```

I've tried searching other questions and answers on here with the same error, and I noticed people mentioning about CR & LF but I still can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: If you wrote it as `elif test "$OPTION" -eq 2; then` -- without all the extra linebreaks -- it'd be easier for a reader (like you!) to see when you leave out the `then` by mistake. That said, this is really a perfect situation to use a case statement instead an if/elif/elif/... block at all.

Comment: ...BTW, I'd suggest testing your error handling code -- you might note that it doesn't actually work, since it's only testing `$?` if no menu option was selected, so if you select an option and something involved in its operation failed, `$?` is never checked. (Also, you use neither `[` or `test` in that code, so it tries to run the expansion of `$?` as a command, not to test its value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use upper-case variable names except for environment variables and built-in shell variables -- doing that increases your risk of namespace collisions. Beyond that, consider a `case` statement:

```
error() { echo "Something went wrong somewhere"; }
trap error ERR

read -p "Select an option [1-6]: " option
case $option in
  1) head "$MLOG" ;;
  2) head "$SLOG" ;;
  3) tail "$MLOG" ;;
  4) tail "$SLOG" ;;
  5) cat  "$MLOG" > ./MessageLogDump.txt
     echo "Message.Log Successfully Dumped in PWD" ;;
  6) cat  "$SLOG" > ./SysLog.txt
     echo "Syslog Successfully Dumped in PWD";;
  *) echo "You selected an incorrect option" ;;
esac
```

Much shorter and easy to read.